# Input/ output file (Capitalization of one letter)

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'am having some trouble with this program and I can not figure what I'am doing wrong; the program still does not allow for the displaying of a file and it still wont capitalize the letter "a". The program is supposed read from the external file input.txt, capitalize all words that begin with the letter "a," and then write them to an external file output.txt.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void nm(string nm, ifstream& xfile);
void mov(ifstream& xfile, string& valfile);
void exam(string& valfile);
void display(string nm, ofstream& yfile, string& valfile);

int main()
{
    ifstream xfile;
    ofstream yfile;
    string valfile;
    nm("input.txt", xfile);
    mov(xfile, valfile);
    exam(valfile);
    display("output.txt", yfile, valfile);
}

void nm(string nm, ifstream& xfile)
{
   xfile.open(nm);
   if (xfile.fail())
   {
       cerr << "Unable to open file \"" << nm << "\" for reading.\n";
       exit(1);
   }
}

void mov(ifstream& xcode, string& valfile)
{
    while (xcode.good())
    {
        valfile += xcode.get();
    }
    xcode.close();
    cout << endl << '[' << valfile[valfile.length()-1] << ']' << endl;
    valfile = valfile.substr( 0, valfile.length()-1 );
}

void exam(string& valfile)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < valfile.length(); i++)
    {
        if(  valfile[i] == 'a' && isspace((int) valfile[i-1]) &&
           ( isspace((int) valfile[i+1]) || isalpha((int) valfile[i+1]) )  )
        {
            valfile[i] = 'A';
        }
    }
}

 void display(string nm, ofstream& yfile, string& valfile)
 {
    yfile.open(nm);
    yfile << valfile;
    yfile.close();
}
```

Comment: did you intend to modify the original file or just to read the file, modify text in memory and then dispaly it? Does your code compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compile your code (on gcc compiler) i had to do these modifications:

1. added `#include <cstdlib>` for `exit` function to be defined
2. changed lines:

   `xfile.open(nm);` into `xfile.open(nm.c_str());`
   `yfile.open(nm);` into `yfile.open(nm.c_str());`

   Because nm is a string and ifstream/ofstream.open takes plain old char array. To convert a  string to char array you use `somestring.c_str()` function.
3. this expression `valfile[valfile.length()-1]` will return you the last character in valfile string... for example valfile[0] will return you just one (First) character from file, if file wasn't empty. To correct it just print out `valfile`:

   ```
   cout << endl << '[' << valfile << ']' << endl;
   ```
4. Add this ugly hack into your exam function to capitalize possible `a` character at the beginning of file:

   ```
   void exam(string& valfile)
   {
       if( (valfile.length()>=1) && (valfile[0]=='a')) valfile[0]='A';
       ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `char*` to `ifstream` constructor, use `c_str()` function.

In `display()`

`yfile.open(nm.c_str());`

In `nm()`

`xfile.open(nm.c_str());`

Add `#include <cstdlib>` for exit

Just got another idea:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    vector <string> v;

    ifstream ip("input.txt");
    ofstream op("output.txt");

    string str;

    while (getline(ip, str))
            v.push_back(str);

    transform(v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        ostream_iterator<string>(op,"\n"),
        [](const string& x){
        stringstream iss(x);
        vector <string> words;
        string s;
        //Split words
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
                 istream_iterator<string>(),
                 back_inserter(words));
        for(auto& it:words)
            if(it[0]=='a')
                it[0]='A';
        s=words[0];
        for(auto it=1;it<words.size();++it)
            s+=" "+words[it]; //Join words
        return s;
        }
        );

    ip.close();
    op.close();
}
//g++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++0x
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start iterating from zero, you're skipping the first character.

```
void exam(string& valfile)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < valfile.length(); i++)
    {
        if(  valfile[i] == 'a' && isspace((int) valfile[i-1]) &&
           ( isspace((int) valfile[i+1]) || isalpha((int) valfile[i+1]) )  )
        {
            valfile[i] = 'A';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by correcting 'exam' function. The way the loop is written now it will access character past the end of the string.

I changed main to read:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s("a a a a a");

    std::cout << "before=[" << s << ']' << std::endl;
    exam(s);
    std::cout << " after=[" << s << ']' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and got:

```
$ ./a.exe 
before=[a a a a a]
 after=[a A A A a]
```

Is this what you want?